# Asyncio stream writer persists data

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, streamwriter

I'm using asyncio to create a websocket between my clients and server.

I am using StreamWriter.write() to send data to and from the client.

```py
    data = {
        "type": "DRAW_RECT",
        "x": x,
        "y": y,
        "color": self.player_color,
        "width": width,
        "height": height,
    }
    data = json.dumps(data)
    self.writer.write(data.encode("utf-8"))
    await self.writer.drain()
```

I have a function which runs whenever the user clicks and moves their mouse. This then sends the data to the server where it can be broadcasted to all clients connected.

However. Occasionally the `writer.write()` data includes the previous data which was sent to the client. I am unsure why it does this. As seen above, I overwrite the `data` variable and insert that directly into the writer.write. I also use writer.drain() to clear it after it has been sent.

Desired data:

```py
'{"type": "DRAW_RECT", "x": 671, "y": 209, "color": [10, 13, 39], "width": 5, "height": 5}'
```

Current data causing the error:

```py
'{"type": "DRAW_RECT", "x": 671, "y": 208, "color": [10, 13, 39], "width": 5, "height": 5}{"type": "DRAW_RECT", "x": 671, "y": 209, "color": [10, 13, 39], "width": 5, "height": 5}'
```

Comment: I believe you problem is that there is no separation between messages, so it's impossible for the receiver to identify where one message ends and the other starts. This is why sometimes it will join them together.

Comment: Hey @bvan , thanks for the response. This does seem to make sense. Do you have any idea how I can separate them? What does this process involve?

Comment: Have you tried changing your receiver to use `readuntil`? It reads until a new line is sent, then you can simply send that new line at the end of the message, adding `\r\n` at the end of `data`.